# Is it possible to not implement a method inherited from an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, implementation

Looking at the Project Server 2010 SDK (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms512767.aspx) in .NET Reflector, I have found something interesting that confuses me.

Apparently, the `SvcProject.ProjectClient` class in `ProjectServerServices.dll` inherits from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Project>`, which is an abstract class that implements the `System.IDisposable` interface.  However, when I inspect the `SvcProject.ProjectClient` class (which is not abstract), there is no `Dispose` method.  What gives?  I thought that every method inherited from interfaces had to be implemented in a concrete implementation (otherwise what's the use of interfaces).  Is .NET Reflector lying to me?  Did Microsoft for some reason circumvent this requirement?  What's going on?

Comment: Abstract classes can have implementations, so it is likely implemented in ClientBase<>.  Otherwise how would an abstract class differ from an interface? Other than preventing multiple-inheritance that is.

Comment: @Brian Rudolph Yeah, I actually did check the base class, but I missed it because it was `IDisposable.Dispose` instead of just `Dispose`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably been implemented *explicitly*, like this:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    // Code here
}
```

Either that or it inherits the method from the base class. Just because `ClientBase<T>` is abstract doesn't mean that it can't have implemented `IDisposable` properly itself. Indeed, it will *have* to either implemented it or redeclared it as an abstract method to force the derived class to implement it.

Either way, the method will be there somehow.

Explicit interface implementation means that the method is only available when the instance is viewed via the interface type. For example:

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {}
}

...

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Dispose(); // Invalid: compile time error
IDisposable d = foo;
d.Dispose();   // Valid
((IDisposable)foo).Dispose(); // Valid (no need for temp variable)
```

Comment: Yeah, it was implemented explicitly in the base class.  I missed it because of it being `IDisposable.Dispose` instead of just `Dispose`.

Answer (score 6):

Without looking, I would say that the base class provides the Dispose method and the concrete class simply doesn't override it.  **EDIT**: And (after looking), it does provide a non-abstract, explicit implementation as `IDisposable.Dispose`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing an implementation in the concrete class (`SvcProject.ProjectClient`), but you were right about the base class providing an implementation. I'm kind of new to C# and am not used to having to cast to an interface in order for the compiler to recognize that a class implements an interface.